# Bigquery SQL Performance issue on tables with cluster and partition

Tags: sql, performance, google-bigquery

I have a simple join between 2 tables with a where clause. Both the tables are partitioned on inserted_date and used cluster on numeric_id column. Even with all of the performance tuning suggested , the query takes a good 30 sec and with different cluster columns the best I can get it is to run for 22 sec. Not sure what I can do to improve the performance.

Note : the table_1 is long with around 100 columns

Table_1
Table Size - 121.18 MB
Rows - 279,567

Table_2
Table Size - 148 MB
Rows - 864,177

```sql
    select q.*,a.product_id
    from table_1 qav
    inner join table_2 a on a.id = qav.application_id
    where a.product_id in (1,5,7,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `a.product_id in (1,5,7,9)` from `where` to `on` and [start with the largest table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute#optimize_your_join_patterns):

```
select q.*,a.product_id 
from table_2 a inner join table_1 qav
on a.id = qav.application_id 
   and a.product_id in (1,5,7,9)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately moving the filter to the join saves just 2-3 sec and there is not much gain .